# Date formula in calculated column - valid

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, microsoft-lists

I have a Microsoft list with two relevant columns '**ACTION Status**' and '**Due Date**'. I am looking for 'ACTION Status' to return Text values based on the 'Due Date' column values. I an using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([DueDate]), "NO DUE DATE!", IF([DueDate] < TODAY(), "OVERDUE", IF([DueDate] <= TODAY() + 30, "DUE NOW", "NO ACTION REQUIRED")))
```

The logic being:

- ISBLANK([Due Date]) checks if the "Due Date" column is empty or does
  not have an entry.
- If the "Due Date" is blank, the formula returns "NO DUE DATE!".
- If the "Due Date" has a value, the formula proceeds to the next
  condition.
- IF([DueDate] < TODAY(), "OVERDUE", IF([DueDate] <= TODAY() + 30,
  "DUE NOW", "NO ACTION REQUIRED")).
- The first condition [DueDate] < TODAY() checks if the "DueDate"
  is earlier than today's date, indicating it's overdue. If true,
  the formula returns "OVERDUE".
- If the first condition is false, it moves to the second condition
  [Due Date] <= TODAY() + 30, which checks if the "Due Date" is 30
  days or less away from today's date. If true, the formula returns
  "DUE NOW".
- If both conditions are false, the formula returns "NO ACTION
  REQUIRED", indicating that no immediate action is needed.

Is this a valid formulae to use for the intended logic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the calculated column formula you are using is valid:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([DueDate]), "NO DUE DATE!", IF([DueDate] < TODAY(), "OVERDUE", IF([DueDate] <= (TODAY() + 30), "DUE NOW", "NO ACTION REQUIRED")))
```

You can also try using `NOW()` instead of `TODAY()` if above formula is not working properly for you.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))